# Why am I getting the following error: NameError: name 'models' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Whenever I run the program, I get the following error:

```
NameError at /table/
name 'models' is not defined
```

It says that there's an error on line 4 in my views.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def display(request):
    return render(request, 'template.tmpl', {'obj': models.Book.objects.all()})
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    publication_year = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /table/
    url(r'^$', views.display, name='display'),
]
```

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing `models.Book` in your view, but you have not imported `models`. In your views.py you need to do `from myapp import models`. Or you can do `from myapp.models import Book` and change it in your view function to just `Book.objects.all()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer in 7 minutes when it let's me